# unclear transformation in identity proof from a textbook

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have $a+b+c=\pi$ and are given the task to prove that 
$$\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)=4\cos\left(\frac a2\right)\cos\left(\frac b2\right)\cos\left(\frac c2\right)$$

The first steps of the proof are described as

$$\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)=\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(\pi-a-b)=\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(a+b)=2\sin\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {a-b}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)$$

I've [managed to understand](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDNcbYfg2Ng) why there is $\sin(a+b)$. What I wonder about is how did the authors of the textbook turn this term into $2\sin\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used the formula $$sin(2x)=2\sin(x)cos(x)$$ So $$sin(2\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)) = 2 sin\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)cos\left(\frac {a+b}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. For the last step use that
$\cos(x)+\cos(y)=
2\,\cos \left( x/2+y/2 \right) \cos \left( x/2-y/2 \right)$
and
$\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{c}{2}$

Comment: Thank you, Doctor! You probably meant to say $\frac {a+b}{2}=\frac {\pi-c}{2}$

Comment: yes of course it is a typo of mine